# how to check the checkbox that is binded to db is check in my controller in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
   public partial class News {

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public News() {
        this.Seminarparticipants = new HashSet<Seminarparticipants>();
    }

    public int NewsID { get; set; }
    public string NewsTitle { get; set; }
    public string NewsDescription { get; set; }
    public string NewsImageUrl { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsSeminar { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Seminarparticipants> Seminarparticipants { get; set; }
}
```

}

this is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "News", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsTitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsImageUrl, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("NewsImageUrl").Multiple(false)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsSeminar)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsSeminar)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsSeminar)
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my controller

```
public ActionResult Create(News news, HttpPostedFileBase NewsImageUrl,bool IsSeminar)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
                string imagename = "no-photo.jpg";
                if (NewsImageUrl != null)
                {
                    imagename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") +
                                Path.GetExtension(NewsImageUrl.FileName);
                    NewsImageUrl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/NewsImage/Images/" + imagename));
                    //------------------------Resize Image------------------------------
                    ImageResizer img = new ImageResizer();
                    img.Resize(Server.MapPath("/NewsImage/Images/" + imagename),
                        Server.MapPath("/NewsImage/Thumb/" + imagename));
                }
                news.NewsImageUrl = imagename;
                news.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;

            //-------------Seminar------------------------

            if (IsSeminar)
            {
                news.IsSeminar = true;
                db.Seminarparticipants.Add(new Seminarparticipants()
                {
                    NewsID = news.NewsID,
                    FullName = String.Empty,
                    Phone = String.Empty,
                    Email = String.Empty
                });
            }
            else
            {
                news.IsSeminar = false;
            }

            db.News.Add(news);
            db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(news);
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand what the question is here?

Comment: also, please don't just dump **all** your code, Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: please write the correct view. I have suggested deleting all that you wrote in Html because it is not useful for the question. Please add only the boolean code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you need to import IsSeminar into the controller's parameters?
When you send the object of News, the model binder will do it for you.

so my suggestion is:

```
public ActionResult Create(News news, HttpPostedFileBase NewsImageUrl)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         if (news.IsSeminar)
         {
         }
     }
}
```

Because the News object has a property of IsSeminar with the same name, the binder will understand it and create the correct object.

Comment: thanks for your reply,samy sammour, i have done what you said,but it gives me this error  ( Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.)

Comment: What is the inner Error? that means it failed with ModelState.IsValid.
please try to set a breakpoint and keep us up to date

Comment: i have set breakpoint and i found the problem on these fields                          FullName = String.Empty,
                    Phone = String.Empty,
                    Email = String.Empty    i deleted them and problem solved. thanks a lot

Comment: That is great, happy for you, can you please mark this as an answer for the other people who have the same problem.

Comment: would you plz tell me how should i do that? I am not very familiar with this website.

Comment: please press the check button on the left side of the answer under the rating arrows.

Comment: Please accept my edit to the question for better quality. You can do it by following the notifications on the top right side next to your name and login information. I suggest you read the manual of the website, it will help. :)